# change date format in excel data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Column which has number format as **dd-mm-yyyy**. Formatting of values are working fine.

Now, I need to add *StartDate* limit to that particular column, using *Date* criteria in *Data Validation*.

When I tried to set *StartDate* as '15-12-2001', I'm getting an error message: "*the start date you entered is invalid*". But, if I enter *StartDate* as '12-15-2011' (ie, of format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'), its working fine.

How can I changes the date format in data validation to accept *StartDate* in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format?

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Good question, with good answers, but not programming related.  Should be migrated to Superuser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most probably have your computers regional settings (accesible via control panel) set to a US type (**mm-dd-yyyy**). So you can either

- Change the regional setting via control panel
- Use the `DATE` function instead (which I would recommend given there is likely to be a good reason for your regional settings being a certain way)

The picture below

1. Has my machine set to US settings
2. has column A formmatted as **dd-mm-yyyy**
3. has used data validation using the `DATE` function to set a range of 15-Dec-2001 to 20-Dec-2001

If you look at the formula bar you can seen I have entered 12/17/2001 in **mm-dd-yyyy** format (ie 17th Dec 2001) and the validation has accepted it, then the cell is reformated to 17-12-2001 by the **dd-mm-yyyy** format

[image: dates]

Comment: But, still I won't be able to enter date value in dd-mm-yyyy format. Instead, I have to enter in mm-dd-yyyy format, which will automatically get converted to dd-mm-yyyy format.
My doubt is, Is it possible to enter the value in dd-mm-yyyy format itself?

Comment: @abhilashca - only if you change the regional settings. Entering the data in **mm-dd-yyyy** or `DATE(yyyy,mm,dd)` is the workaround to not changing this setting

Answer (score 4):

I come across these type of questions often at work, although not yet that exact one you have asked. My firsrt inclination is to check regional settings on your computer. Believe it or not, this area controls what Excel deems as a decimal point and things of that nature. There is an area under Regional settings that specifies your date format. Your specific format of 'dd-mm-yyy' is listed there. I would start with that.

Comment: +1 for providing what I think is the likely cause just before I did.

Comment: @alfonsopilato - My regional settings is in en-us, I haven't changed anything. However, my intention is to achieve the date formatting, without changing the regional settings.

Comment: You can't change the regional setting on your computer because then it won't match your keyboard. Yes you can set you keyboard seperately, but that already drives me crazy, if the default setting does not match my keyboard it will use the wrong setting even more often.

Answer (score 0):

When applying the validation use the Date option and apply Start & End dates accordingly.

Format the cell to use dd/mm/yyyy format - once valid date is entered it will be formatted as required regardless of how it was input (eg 1/2/9 will display correctly as 01/02/2009)